# how to align three divs to meet responsiveness using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to display three divs horizontally on a web page in my laptop screen and show them vertically on a same page in mobile screen using bootstrap ( responsive design) How to do that?

Here is code

```
<div id="form1_container" class="container-fluid">
<form class="msform" id="form1">
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />

</fieldset>
</form></div>
<div id="form2_container"><form class="msform" class="container-fluid" id="form2">
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Socia Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 2</h3>
        <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" />
        <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" />
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-

button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" 

value="Next" />
</fieldset>
</form></div>

<div id="form3_container" class="container-fluid">
<form class="msform" id="form3"><fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Create Your Account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 3</h3>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="UserName" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
        <input type="password" name="passwordC" placeholder="Confirm 

Password" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-

button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" 

value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form></div>


</div>
```

Comment: read the documentation at: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in [grid system Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.

For your example, you can simply add `class="col-lg-4"` to your `<div>`.

Reminder: don't forget the meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```